# writing mongodb syntax on java api

Tags: java, mongodb, api, syntax

How do I write this query on java api ? ',' means 'or' clause

```
db.questions.find( { user_id: /bc/ },{user_name:/bc/},{age:/2/} )
```

I've tried different ways, but I've been successful using one option only. How to add multiple options using "or" clause ?

here my code :

```
MongoClient mongoClient;
                DB db;

                DBCollection table;
                DBCursor cursor = null;

                mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
                db = mongoClient.getDB("stackoverflow");
                boolean auth = db.authenticate("aku", "kamu".toCharArray());
                table = db.getCollection("questions");
                cursor = table.find(new BasicDBObject("user_id", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("milk")));
                while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                    DBObject object = cursor.next();%>
                    out.print(object.get("user_id"));
                }
```

Using mySQL, the query is :

select * from questions where user_id like '%bc%' or user_name like %bc% or age like %2%

I'm new to mongoDB, I feel like it's fairly hard to convert queries from mySQL..

here the error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$or` operator - [manual link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

```
db.questions.find( "{ $or : [user_id: '/bc/' ,user_name:'/bc/',age:'/2/'] }")
```

You can use this query within java like this:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("questions").find( "{ $or : [user_id: '/bc/' ,user_name:'/bc/',age:'/2/'] }" );

iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
    @Override
    public void apply(final Document document) {
        System.out.println(document);
    }
});
```

Comment: anything else you need mate?

Comment: hey bro, how to apply it on web project (jsp)..it cant be implemented
btw thanks, i just knowing thats way, so the query can be directly writen on java api like that...

Comment: i would recommend you to check a tutorial on this matter.

Comment: sure bro, here the picture of error i upload on the questions, can you make it clear bro?

Comment: dont forget " around the find. i will edit my post aswell

Comment: where's your post mate?

Comment: i mean my answer. i forgot to add "" around the find query aswell

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your question is already answered but if you're using a later version or mongodb java driver, it can be written this way. I'm not familiar with how BasicDBObject works, am more used to Documents. Both works.

```
List<Document> orQueryList = new ArrayList<Document>();
orQueryList.add("user_id", "bc");
orQueryList.add("user_name", "bc");
orQueryList.add("age", "2");

Document orDoc = new Document("$or", orQueryList);

MongoCursor<Document> cursor = table.find(orDoc).iterator();

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
   Document dbObj = cursor.next();

   System.out.println(dbObj.getString("user_id");
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping @tan kim loong, actually my questions is not answered yet, i use mongoDB api version 2.X, i'll try your answer to implement my source...

Comment: It should mean that your "user_id" field is an Integer. Use `dbObj.getInteger("user_id")` or `Integer.parseInt(dbObj.get("user_Id").toString())` instead.